# The type initializer for 'weka.core.WekaPackageManager' threw an exception - weka c#

Tags: java, c#, .net, weka, ikvm

I am using weka api through c#. I have converted weka jar file to c# dll by using ikvm. Then I have added the converted dll `(wekacsharp.dll)` in my reference.

I have also added `ikvm.gnu.classpath.dll`, `IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll`, `IKVM.OpenJDK.Util.dll`, `IKVM.OpenJDK.Text.dll`, `IKVM.OpenJDK.Core` in my reference.

I am trying to use *j48 algorithm* but i am getting the error. Screen shot of code error is attached. Kindly check it and suggest me something to fix it.

Code:

```
public static void classifyTest()
{
    try
    {
        weka.core.Instances insts = new weka.core.Instances(new java.io.FileReader("iris.arff"));
        insts.setClassIndex(insts.numAttributes() - 1);

        weka.classifiers.Classifier cl = new weka.classifiers.trees.J48();
        //Console.WriteLine("Performing " + percentSplit + "% split evaluation.");

        //randomize the order of the instances in the dataset.
        // weka.filters.Filter myRandom = new weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.Randomize();
        // myRandom.setInputFormat(insts);
        // insts = weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(insts, myRandom);

        int trainSize = insts.numInstances() *  percentSplit / 100;
        int testSize = insts.numInstances() - trainSize;
        weka.core.Instances train = new weka.core.Instances(insts, 0, trainSize);

        cl.buildClassifier(train);
        int numCorrect = 0;
        for (int i = trainSize; i < insts.numInstances(); i++)
        {
            weka.core.Instance currentInst = insts.instance(i);
            double predictedClass = cl.classifyInstance(currentInst);
            if (predictedClass == insts.instance(i).classValue())
                numCorrect++;
        }
        //java.io.Console.WriteLine(numCorrect + " out of " + testSize + " correct (" +(double)((double)numCorrect / (double)testSize * 100.0) + "%)");
    }
    catch (java.lang.Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Show your code and exception message as a text, not as an image.

Comment: And it would seem that there is an `InnerException` in your exception, would be good to check it for additional information

Comment: just added two more references and the code is fixed now/// thanks :)

Comment: 1. IKVM.OpenJDK.Beans
2. IKVM.OpenJDK.SwingAWT

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you did not skip the conversion of the weka.jar to weka.dll using Ikvm before adding it as a reference to your C# project.

#### Conversion from Java to a .NET dll

With that out of the way, the first thing you will want to do is to convert the Weka .jar file into a .NET dll. To do this, we will use ikvmc, which is the IKVM static compiler.

On the console, go to the directory which contains weka.jar, and type:

```
ikvmc -target:library weka.jar
```

The `-target:library` call causes ikvmc to create a .dll library instead of an executable.

Note that the IKVM tutorial tells you that you should add

```
-reference:/usr/lib/IKVM.GNU.Classpath.dll
```

(or appropriate path) to the above command, it tells IKVM where to find the GNU Classpath library. However, IKVM.GNU.Classpath.dll is no longer included in the download package, and is from very old versions of IKVM. When Sun open sourced Java, it got replaced by the IKVM.OpenJDK.*.dll files.

You should now have a file called "weka.dll", which is a .NET version of the entire weka API. That's exactly what we want!

#### Use the dll in a .NET application

To try it out, let's use a small C# program that I wrote. The program simply runs the J48 classifier on the Iris dataset with a 66% test/data split, and prints out the correctness percentage. It also uses a few Java classes, and is already about 95% legal Java code.